# Cold Temperature Glue

Tags: refrigerator

The plastic piece that holds together the 2 ice crusher blades in my ice dispenser broke. Is there a glue that could withstand the freezer temperature I can use?

Comment: I would think that any CAA "super glue" should work.

Comment: are the metal blades for crushing ice pushing on the plastic? I first thought of JB weld metal filled  epoxy but a [2 part  non metal epoxy might work better](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Gorilla-7-8-fl-oz-General-Purpose-Epoxy-42001/100670610) I have had good luck with Gorilla brand glues.

Answer (score 1):

I had to test this myself when 'gluing' an aluminum mounting plate to a stainless steel door. No 'glue' or epoxy that I tried worked under a repeated freeze / heat cycle test.
 What did work was RTV silicone rubber. Your chioce of colors. If the stress is too much for this application, 2-part epoxies designed for wide temperature range might work.
 Over-build the RTV or epoxy at the break so it will have a better grip.
 Give them 2 days to fully set before use
 I might add that if the torque at this location is very high (it did break there after all) and neither epoxy or RTV will hold then you may need to surf the web based on the make and model of freezer and try to order just the broken part.